# Read Mails and folder list from Microsoft Exchange Server using objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exchange-server

I am new to ios device application programming,
I want to read folder list and mails from Microsoft Exchange server programatically.

Any one can please direct me into right direction..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use EWS, EAS, or OWA for Exchange service.

1)if you want o use OWA service, check the below link,you will get wrapper class for OWA exchange.

https://github.com/jgallen23/OWAParser

2)EWS

For Ews i converted Services.wsdl(Describes the contract between client and server) to objetiveC using sudzc and made changes in Sudzc generated code.

Check below links also

**// request for read mail**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566107(v=exchg.140).aspx

**// request for get folder list**

/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa564829(v=exchg.140).aspx

3)EAS

i hope below lnik will be helpful for EAS exchange developement.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2011/09/28/new-to-exchange-activesync-development.aspx